# Print hexadecimal array sorted

Tags: arrays, perl, printing, hex

I have an array of hexadecimal values. I want to sort them and print them sorted. I only get the sorted array printed as numerical items.

The code so far is this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my @numbers = ( 0x23, 0xAA, 0xaa, 0x01, 0xfB  );

my @sorted_numbers = sort { $a <=> $b } @numbers;

print @sorted_numbers;
```

The output is this one:

```
135170170251
```

Comment: When you say `print "@array\n"` (with quotes) spaces get inserted between elements, so you can tell them apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using hex literals, not strings, you made Perl compiler turn them into numbers. Use strings if you want to keep strings, and use `hex` to get their numeric representation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @numbers = ( '0x23', '0xAA', '0xaa', '0x01', '0xfB' );

my @sorted_numbers = sort { hex $a <=> hex $b } @numbers;

print "@sorted_numbers\n";
```

I also included double quotes in print to separate the results.

Answer (score 0):

That's because they're a numeric value, and you haven't told perl how to represent them.

The normal trick for this is to use `printf` or `sprintf`:

```
printf "%x" x @sorted_numbers, @sorted_numbers;
```

Which will print:

```
123aaaafb
```

Or something like:

```
printf "%02x\n", $_ for @sorted_numbers;
```